# java 7/8 for Eclipse luna on Mavericks

Tags: eclipse, osx-mavericks

I'd like to upgrade my eclipse from Kepler to Luna on my OSX Mavericks. I also have some web apps that do not seem to work with Java upgraded beyond the 1.6.0_65 level. Is there a method for installing Java 8 for use with Eclipse Luna, but still retain the 1.6.0_65 version as a default.

Comment: What webapps are we talking about here?

Comment: Web apps that are incompatible with *current* versions of Java need fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple JVMs installed. To set the default JVM to 1.6, set `JAVA_HOME` to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.6.0_65.jdk/Contents/Home`.

To set Eclipse's JVM, [follow VonC's instructions for editing `eclipse.ini`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/142357/139010)

However, Eclipse's JVM<sup>1</sup> is not tied to the JVM which Eclipse uses when running *your* Java applications. Those are configured in Eclipse Preferences, under *Installed JREs.*

[image]

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Eclipse is, of course, a Java application itself, so *it* runs in a JVM.</sub>

Comment: Eclipse 4.4 will not run with OS X Java 6.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen good point, but it doesn't sound like the OP especially cares about the JVM that Eclipse uses.